# dynamically link one lib to another lib at build time, yet link statically into iphone app

Tags: iphone, dynamic-linking

i've got a lib, A, which can be linked into an iPhone app by itself. i'd like to make 2 other libs, B and C, which depend on A.

an app may want to be built by linking the libs statically in any of these combinations: A, A+B, A+C, or A+B+C.

however, when building B or C, i'd like them to link to their dependent lib A dynamically, e.g. B depends on A but does not copy A into itself statically. is this possible?

note: i'm not asking if libs can dynamically link into apps. i'm trying to find out if libs can be dynamically linked to another at compile time, such that the lib does not contain a copy of its dependent lib inside of itself. but at when building an app, the user can statically link any of the above allowable combinations above.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone apps do not support dynamic linking of third-party libraries.

Comment: not quite what i'm going for. i want all libs to statically link into the app, but looking to have libs dynamically linked to their dependent lib.

Comment: Static libraries cannot dynamically link to anything.

Comment: i better edit my question. it's a bit confusing for people to understand what i'm asking.

Comment: You can't mix static and dynamic linking. Library B cannot dynamically link library A without itself being a dynamic library.

Comment: hmm not looking good for me then. this means 4 static lib builds: A, AB, AC, ABC, vs what i was hoping might be doable, 3 lib builds: A, B (dep on A dynamically), C (dep on A dynamically). then building app by linking statically to A optionally with B and/or C.

Comment: Is it really a problem to simply require linking A if you link B or C?

Comment: B uses implementation from A, so static link to A pulls it into B. then building an app requires linking to B without A (since A is in B). Also linking to C if B is there would conflict, since both have A.

Comment: You should be able to compile B as a static library without linking A. I don't remember offhand how to do this, but it's entirely possible to create library B such that B and C are compatible, but linking B requires linking A as well.

Comment: sounds a lot like what i am hoping to do. have B depend on A without A copied in it. have C depend on A without A copied in it. B and C independent of each other but can coexist in an app if wanted. ultimately compile an app with A, A and B, A and C, or A and B and C. right now A always gets pulled into B, so the output file is much larger than what is wanted and a conflict with C will arise as well. not sure how to build B without A getting copied in.

Comment: thanks for discussing, kevin. got me going in the right direction. figured out that simply not having A in the lib path avoids it copied into B during B's build. then statically linking A, or B with A, to an executable is possible.